# ResultSet not returning av values from selected table

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist, resultset

I've encountered a bit of a perplexing problem. I've got this simple method for extracting data from a table using SELECT *... However, when it iterates through the table it stops the iteration before it's gone through all entries in said table. I've used the debugger to the extent of eliminating the problem areas to when the rows are added to the ArrayList. But still, it stops before it should stop. Any ideas?

```
    public static ArrayList<Actors> acList() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Actors> acList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
    try {
        getConnection();            
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Actors");            
        ResultSet rst = st.executeQuery();
        Actors ac;           
        while (rst.next()) {
            ac = new Actors(rst.getInt("ActorId"), rst.getString("fName"), rst.getString("eName"),
            rst.getInt("Age"), rst.getInt("NoOfCredits"), rst.getString("Country"));
            acList.add(ac);   
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {           
    }
    return acList;  
}
```

Comment: `} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`?

Comment: That helped tremendously! Quick and easy, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, posting if anyone else encounters similar problems. What had happened was that one row in my mysql table had an entry (Which i believed to have deleted) that wasn't matching types with what I was trying to extract. The list attempted to claim an int but the value in the row was varchar. Edited the table so it was correct types. Now it works ^^